# Micro USB port charges only (no data)

Tags: usb, samsung-galaxy-tab-s-2

I connected my Galaxy Tab S2 to my (previously working) Ethernet adapter, only to find it would only charge (no Ethernet). However, charging (up to 2A) still works fine.

I've tried:

- connecting a new Ethernet adapter, a generic OTG adapter, and a USB cable to a PC (these all worked before). None of these worked, but they all worked on other devices.
- checking the Micro USB port for damage. There is none.
- Connecting the USB cable to a PC would start charging, but data did not work (it would be read as an AC charger, there would be no "Slow charging" message, and there was no "USB charging only" or "USB debugging enabled" notification).

Everything else (including charging as mentioned above) still works perfectly.

What is wrong with my tablet?

Comment: It is highly likely that the M-USB is faulty. Try another one.

Comment: @DanishShakeel A different device with a Micro USB port? I've tried that and all the adapters/cords worked on a different device.

Comment: Does the problem persist with all the cables?

Comment: @DanishShakeel Yes, I tried a 6ft nylon cable and the original Samsung cable and both of them only charged (syncing worked on other devices).